# JavaScript - Loop Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have this code which uses a typewriter animation to replace the *placeholder* text in a search bar:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vQmRjM

```
////////////////////////////
// Twitter: @mikedevelops
////////////////////////////

// your custome placeholder goes here!
var typetext = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];  
var typetext = typetext[Math.floor(Math.random() * typetext.length)];   
var searchBar = $('#search');
    // placeholder loop counter
var phCount = 0;

// function to return random number between
// with min/max range
function randDelay(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)+min);
}

// function to print placeholder text in a 
// 'typing' effect
function printLetter(string, el) {
    // split string into character separated array
    var arr = string.split(''),
        input = el,
        // store full placeholder
        origString = string,
        // get current placeholder value
        curPlace = $(input).attr("placeholder"),
        // append next letter to current placeholder
        placeholder = curPlace + arr[phCount];

    setTimeout(function(){
        // print placeholder text
        $(input).attr("placeholder", placeholder);
        // increase loop count
        phCount++;
        // run loop until placeholder is fully printed
        if (phCount < arr.length) {
            printLetter(origString, input);
        }
    // use random speed to simulate
    // 'human' typing
    }, randDelay(50, 90));
}  

// function to init animation
function placeholder() {    
    $(searchBar).attr("placeholder", "");
    printLetter(typetext, searchBar);
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    placeholder();
    }, 3000);
```

I added a *setInterval* to loop through the different *placeholder* text every few seconds, however after the first iteration it just starts showing *undefined*.

Any ideas where I have went wrong?

Comment: Well, your overwriting the array, the very next line, with just a string, from one of the values from the array.

Comment: I thing   $('#search').attr("placeholder", ""); may solve .But your code is like correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to access the array item from an index which does not really exist. You have to reset the variable *phCount* in each call of `setInterval()`:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  phCount = 0; // reset here
  placeholder();
}, 3000);
```

**Code Example:**

```js
////////////////////////////
// Twitter: @mikedevelops
////////////////////////////

// your custome placeholder goes here!
var typetext = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"]; 
var typetext = typetext[Math.floor(Math.random() * typetext.length)]; 
var searchBar = $('#search');
 // placeholder loop counter
var phCount = 0;

// function to return random number between
// with min/max range
function randDelay(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)+min);
}

// function to print placeholder text in a 
// 'typing' effect
function printLetter(string, el) {
  // split string into character seperated array

  var arr = string.split(''),
  input = el,
  // store full placeholder
  origString = string,
  // get current placeholder value
  curPlace = $(input).attr("placeholder"),
  // append next letter to current placeholder
  placeholder = curPlace + arr[phCount];
  //console.log(curPlace + '::' + arr[phCount] + '::' + phCount)

  setTimeout(function(){
  // print placeholder text
  $(input).attr("placeholder", placeholder);
  // increase loop count
  phCount++;

  // run loop until placeholder is fully printed
  if (phCount < arr.length) {
    printLetter(origString, input);
  }
  // use random speed to simulate
  // 'human' typing
  }, randDelay(50, 90));
}  

// function to init animation
function placeholder() { 
  $(searchBar).attr("placeholder", "");
  printLetter(typetext, searchBar);
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  phCount = 0;
  placeholder();
}, 3000);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);

html {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00c6ff 10%, #0072ff 90%);  
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(black, .5);
}

h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.search {
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid darken(white, 30%);
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.submit {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: url('http://thesuiteworld.com/wp-admin/maint/search-icon-white-png-540.png') no-repeat center center, #1E1E20;
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <h1>Placeholder text with<br/> typing effect</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input class="search" type="text" id="search" />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value=" " />
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Click search to reset</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove undefined, You need to reset the char length loop setting

update following code to reset the string length to 0

```js
if (phCount  arr.length) {
     printLetter(origString, input);
    }
 else {
  phCount = 0;
 }
```

and to display next string use following code

```js
var wordcount =0;
window.setInterval(function(){
 
    if (wordcount >= typetext.length) {
        wordcount = 0;
 }
 
 placeholder(wordcount);
 wordcount++;
}, 3000);
```

This will loop the array of string. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reset the `phCount` to `0` when you reset the placeholder `($(searchBar).attr("placeholder", ""))`.